# Ubuntu installer for Dell laptop

Tags: dell, raspberrypi

Where can I find instructions on how to create a Ubuntu installer thumb drive for a DELL LAPTOP but using a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Canonical has a tutorial for this. Create Live Ubuntu [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

You may create Ubuntu LiveUSB with https://www.balena.io/etcher/
All you need to do is download latest Ubuntu ISO into your notebook and run https://www.balena.io/etcher/ in order to create Ubuntu LiveUSB.